# Next.js 13 routing params

Tags: next.js, routes, next-link, next.js13

Hi folks first of all i am new to react and nextjs. So i am sorry if my question is stupid.

I am currently building a navigation with nextjs 13 within new the app folder. Here is my navigation component where i am building the category links with the  component:

```
import React from 'react'
import fetchMainNavigation from '../lib/fetchMainNavigation'
import Link from 'next/link'

const DesktopNavigation = async () => {
  const categories = await fetchMainNavigation

  return (
    <nav className={'hidden md:flex'}>
      <ul className={'flex flex-row gap-4'}>
        {categories.map((category) => (
          <li key={category.id}>
            <Link
              href={`${category.id}`}
              className={
                'hover:underline hover:text-gold hover:scale-110 transition-transform duration-200'
              }
            >
              {category.name}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default DesktopNavigation

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const categories = await fetchMainNavigation

  return categories.map((category) => ({
    categoryId: category.id.toString(),
  }))
}
```

I have also created a dynamic route "/app/[categoryId]/page.jsx". The routing works fine but now i have a not readable URL like "www.mypage.com/46asdfg56as8g" but i want something like "www.mypage.com/food". I know i could use the category name for routing but i need the categoryId as param within "/app/[categoryId]/page.jsx" to fetch information about the current active category. Is there a way to achieve this?

I have already searched the Next.js 13 documentation and also searched stackoverflow and other sources, but can't find anything about this problem yet.

Answer (score 3):

js 13.4.4 they call this "Dynamic Routes", if you want this route in the browser "www.mypage.com/food" and then you need some detail, for example "www.mypage.com/food/1".

You need to create this folder structure in your project.

/src/app/food/page.tsx - List of food
/src/app/food/[id]/page.tsx - Detail of food

You can read the id param, passing props to component

```
export default function Page({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
   const { id } = params;

   return <p>{id}</p>

}
```

This is the link to the documentation

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated doc

```
'use client';
 
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const params = useParams();
 
  // Route -> /shop/[tag]/[item]
  // URL -> /shop/shoes/nike-air-max-97
  // `params` -> { tag: 'shoes', item: 'nike-air-max-97' }
  console.log(params);
 
  return <></>;
}
```

Comment: Bad answer. Neither applicable to all versions of Nextjs13 nor typesafe.

Answer (score -1):

It is in the beta documentation [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/page). Also, under the very first category of the docs [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#dynamic-segments)

To utilize the next13 beta slugs, simply pass them in as the params property, as outlined in the official documentation.

```
const DesktopNavigation = async ({ params }) => {
  const category = params['category'];
  ...
}
```